# Unable to set adSize property. Not enough space to show ad with custom size

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

I am trying to use a Smart Banner in landscape, but though the requirements very specifically state a height of 32 by screen width, I cannot avoid the error message about the adSize property. The ad will appear within my app, but it clips on the bottom.

```
bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
bannerView.rootViewController = self
bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
```

These are the only lines of code I have related to the view. The rest is within the storyboard. I have a GADBannerView with height = 32, width = superview, space to bottom = 0, and horizontal centering within superview. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: So after further inspecting the error, it appears as though the bannerView is effectively ignoring Auto-Layout. It is attempting to load the ad into the literal width of the view in the storyboard, not the actual width of the screen. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I ran into same issue - PLEASE , hava anybody an idear to fix it? I can#t see an difference between the adMOB ExampleBannerViewApp an my project. I cleaned all constraints from Storyboard and start from beginning over and over again. I also used "self.bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner;" but also no luck to see the TestBanner at my Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Set the INTRINSIC SIZE for your GADBannerView (its at the bottom of the property inspector window - the one that looks like a ruler) to something like 320 x 50 and select PLACEHOLDER instead of Default. Remove any bounds that bind the GADBannerView to the sides of the screen. Center the GADBannerView and bind it to the top or bottom of the UIViewController - wherever you are going to place the ad.

I had the same issue and this fixed it - the banner is autoresized using the kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape size and no error!!